# EasyMock chained method call producing null pointer exception

Tags: java, easymock

I am using EasyMock to try and mock iteration through a list of items that are two levels deep.  My unit test code is below

```
    EventContext ctx = EasyMock.createMock(EventContext.class);
    Order order = EasyMock.createMock(Order.class);
    Item oli = new Item();
    oli.setProduct(370);
    List<Item> lineItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    lineItems.add(oli);
    EasyMock.expect(ctx.getOrder()).andReturn(order).times(2);
    EasyMock.expect(order.getTopLevelLineItems()).andReturn(lineItems);
```

and the code it is attempting to test is

```
    for(Item item : (List<Item>) ctx.getOrder().getTopLevelLineItems()) {
            if(370 == item.getProduct()) {
                result = true;
            }
```

But when the unit test runs I get a NullPointerException on the line below:

```
for(Item item : (List<Item>) ctx.getOrder().getTopLevelLineItems())
```

It seems like I have set up the chained call correctly does anyone have any suggestions of what might be going wrong here?

Edit: I want to add I split out the chain into different lines in the class being tested and it appears that the ctx.getOrder() is not null but the lineItems returned are

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add the EasyMock.replay();

```
    EventContext ctx = EasyMock.createMock(EventContext.class);
    Order order = EasyMock.createMock(Order.class);
    Item oli = new Item();
    oli.setProduct(370);
    List<Item> lineItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    lineItems.add(oli);

    EasyMock.expect(order.getTopLevelLineItems()).andReturn(lineItems).times(2);
    EasyMock.replay(order);
    EasyMock.expect(ctx.getOrder()).andReturn(order).times(2);
    EasyMock.replay(ctx);
```

Comment: Just tried it.  Doing this results in a null pointer on

    EasyMock.expect(ctx.getOrder().getTopLevelLineItems()).andReturn(lineItems)

Comment: Put the reply after all the expect calls. Otherwise the mocks won't be in the right "state".